# How to present an XML file in HTML format in different ways, according to user input?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file consisting of book nodes, and each book contains 1-4 authors, 1 title & 1 Year

I've also created an XSL file related to the above XML file so that whenever I open the XML file in a browser, its contents are presented in a html table format consisting of 3 rows "Author","Title","Year"

What I want to do now is create an HTML file that will present the above table but not all of its contents, only the ones asked through user input (appropriate fields for user input should be found on that same html file as well I guess..)

e.g. a user can type in the name of an author, or a year, or a title, or a word contained in a title or in an author's name and then have the appropriate table presented to him.

I'm a new to all this so my questions are the following :

1. Will I have to mess with the content in the XML and XSL files again or should I leave them intact from now on and only deal with the html file I'll be creating?
2. In order to achieve what I want what should my html file contain? Javascript functions that will be presenting only parts of the XML file but always according to the XSL file? Will I be using XSLT in the html file again or simply javascript?

What I need is to create smth that will take input from the user (javascript?) and then use a parser (XSLT?) to parse through the XML according to the user's input? and then return the result on screen filtered through the XSL template I created??

Could someone please indicate me the process I should follow step by step (not in detail but in which order should I deal with all the issues involved in this..) ?

Thank you very much for your understanding and help! I know there's lots of information on w3schools but the problem is that everything is fragmented and I still don't know how to combine all that, in which order and which method to choose!

btw. I don't want to use jquery for this, only XML,XSLT,XPATH,HTML,Javascript standards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to pass the user-wanted processing as parameter(s) to the transformation**.

Read about the `xsl:param` instruction.

External parameters to the transformation can be any globally declared (children of the top element `xsl:stylesheet`) `xsl:param` elements.

**The way the invoker of the XSLT transformation specifies the values for these parameters on invoking the transformation is implementation - dependent** and varies from one XSLT processor to another. You need to read the documentation of the particular XSLT processor for the exact information how to do this.

**For example**, if the XSLT processor is the .NET XslCompiledTransform, the way to pass parameters to the transformation is via the **[`XsltArgumentList.AddParam()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx)** method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the XSL and XML files to the javascript, you can use ajax requests for that, and you can use an iframe to load them for you. Once you have them in javascript you can use XPath and XSLT to do exactly what you want.

For example, here's a simple way to load an xml and then use XPath on it using the iframe way, it uses the input value to query the xml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> xml test </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xml = null;

        function getXml(path) {
            document.getElementById("loader").src = path;
        }

        function loaded(frm) {
            if (frm.contentWindow) {
                xml = frm.contentWindow.document;
            }
        }

        function query() {
            var value = document.getElementById("query").value;
            var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();
                var result = evaluator.evaluate("//" + value, 
                    xml, 
                    null, 
                    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
                    null);

                console.log(result.singleNodeValue);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Query the xml: <input type="text" id="query" />
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="query()" />
    <iframe style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;" id="loader" onload="loaded(this)"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        getXml("index.xml");
    </script>
</body>
```

As for the XSLT part, here's a tutorial for how to do that: [XSLT - On the Client](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp). In this tutorial they also show how to load the files using ajax.
You can of course load the XSL file just like the XML one in my example.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input Nitzan! I'm afraid I cannot use Ajax or iFrame or PHP for that matter but still I'll try and make use of your advice!It's still very confusing when it comes to order etc. but I guess it's best that I keep looking into w3schools afterall and comebck with more concrete questions..

Comment: Why can't you use iframes nor ajax?

Comment: It's an assignment that I have and we're only allowed to use XML,XSLT,XPATH,HTML,Javascript unofortunately. The only problem is I still aven't figured out where to start from and which tool is for what.. I'll need the html file to present the user with search fields, buttons & table that will change according to what the user is looking for....

Comment: iframe is a valid html tag, and with javascript you can use it to load data, it's within your constraints.